# Shell script create unexpected file "start" on starting process

Tags: bash, shell

I've found and modified a simple shell script to start/stop a jar, but when launching the script it creates an extra empty `start` file.

I cannot understand why. Any clue?

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
    start)
        if [[ -e myprog.pid  ]]
        then
            echo "myprog.pid found. Is myprog already running?"
        else
            exec java -jar myprog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 1>/dev/null 2>$1 &
            echo $! > myprog.pid;
        fi
        ;;
    stop) 
        kill $(cat myprog.pid);
        rm myprog.pid
        ;;
    *) 
        echo "usage: myprog {start|stop}" ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: From here, it's impossible to know what's happening. Please decompile the jar-file and show the correponding source code.

Comment: @Dominique It's not abut the jar. If I start the jar without the script the file is not created.

Comment: `exec` and `&` don't make sense together. Not the problem just a point of information. Drop the `exec`. You don't want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is `2>$1`. That's a typo.

You meant `2>&1`.

What you wrote is expanded by the shell as `2>start` and creates your file.

Comment: Thanks! Totally missed it!

Comment: For the record while http://www.shellcheck.net/ doesn't specifically catch this (because it can't) it would have caused you to go "huh?" when it warned you to quote your variable expansion in that location.

Comment: I didn't know about it, added to favs (next to regex101)! Ahah